# Synching 4 external hard drive to Desktop with Vista 64 and Laptop with Win7 64

Tags: windows-7, windows, hard-drive, windows-vista, external-hard-drive

I have to reformat my SSD in my Vista Desktop. I backed it up 9 months ago but the external drives were fresh. Now I need to re-backup my documents, photos etc. What is the best way without going though each folder and letting Windows copy, and merge files?
I want to be able to have the same doucments etc.. on my laptop as well as my Desktop. I have several external drives aquired over the years. Why not have each drive current? It would be great if each drive plugged into either PC could just synch on the connection.